# C++: Adding values to a class object during the declaration?

Tags: c++, class

I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure this crap out.  I'm in the last week of a CS 142 intro to computer programming class at college, and I've done totally fine up until now.  I've understood all the concepts and have done totally fine on the homework, but classes and pointers are kicking my butt.  I just can't wrap my head around them.  I have been working on the latest homework assignment and thought I was starting to understand classes just fine, but any time I try to implement or call information, I get crazy errors.  I have no idea what to do.  Can anyone help me and explain things without getting super crazy?

The assignment is to write a program that will keep track of inventory at a Car Dealership.  The professor has provided a pre-written class called "Car" that we are to implement in the code that keeps track of the make, color, and price of each car, as well as having member functions that allow you to paint a car a different color and to print out a list of the current inventory.  The problem is that all of the input required for the Car class does NOT have a member function for adding data.  I've searched and searched, and all the solutions I've found have included member functions for adding data to the object, but my professor's included class (that we MUST use and are forbidden to modify) has no member function like that.  So I have no idea how to get data into the object.  Here is the entire Car.h and Car.cpp:

Car.h

```
//WARNING: It is expressly forbidden to modify any part of this document, including its name.
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class Car
{
    private:
    string name;
    string color;
    double price;

public:
    /* 
     * Constructor/Destructor
     * 
     * Handles creation and deletion of Car objects.
     * 
     * Parameter: name_in
     *      The name of a new car
     * Parameter: color_in
     *      The color of a new car
     * Parameter: price_in
     *      The price of a new car
     */
    Car(string name_in, string color_in, double price_in);
    virtual ~Car();

    string getName();
    string getColor();
    double getPrice();
    void paint(string new_color);
    string toString();
};
```

Car.cpp

```
//WARNING: It is expressly forbidden to modify any part of this document, including its name
#include "Car.h"
using namespace std;

Car::Car(string name_in, string color_in, double price_in)
{
    name = name_in;
    color = color_in;
    price = price_in;
}
Car::~Car(){}
string Car::getName()
{
    return name;
}
string Car::getColor()
{
    return color;
}
double Car::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}
void Car::paint(string new_color)
{
    color = new_color;
    price += 1000;
}
string Car::toString()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "Name: " << name << endl;
    ss << "Color: " << color << endl;
    ss << "Price: $" << price << endl;
    return ss.str();
}
```

So I have to use the Car class to add three values to the object - name, color, and price, and I have to store these in a vector of Car objects so there can be a list of user-defined length in the inventory, and I have to be able to write and read .txt files that can add to the vector by adding a new Car object based on the text. Like I said, other implementations of ideas like this that I've Googled have all had member functions that allow for adding to the data in the object, but my professor's code does not.  I somehow have to initialize it when I first set up the object.  Obviously, the only exception is the color of the car, which can be altered using the paint(string new_color) function.

I've tried tons of different ways of setting up a car object in my own Main.cpp file using everything my brain can think of having learned in class this semester.  I've tried stuff like
    cars[0] = new Car("Jalopy", "Blue", 2300);
or
    cars.push_back(Car("Camaro", "Yellow", 25000));
and I've tried using pointers (but I don't really know how to use them) and everything. and AAAAAAAUGGGHHH I'm so stuck! How do I get a new Car object and set it up in the vector and initialize the object with a name, a color, and a price without using class member functions to add the data for me?

P.S. the professor's instructions are totally useless and says "It is required that you use the provided Car class (found in Car.h and Car.cpp) to store all car information."  That is literally the only help he has given us as far as the class implementation is concerned.  Please help!

Comment: `cars.push_back(Car("Camaro", "Yellow", 25000));` which you mention is the right way to do it. You apparently have some wrong idea about 1. creating the object 2. "adding data" to it. The line with `push_back` adds to the vector a car Camaro with the price 25000. What do you want to "add" to this object, while it already have all the info - name, colour, price?

Comment: I just have absolutely no idea of what the syntax would be for setting up a "Car" object with the required three sets of information: name, color, price.  When I try cars.push_back(Car("Camaro", "Yellow", 25000)); I get one of two errors: "class 'Car' has no member 'push_back'" or "Expression must have class type" if I'm trying to use the object vector as a pointer.

Comment: This is the syntax: `Car("Camaro", "Yellow", 25000)`. It creates Car object with given name, colour and price.

Comment: *"some of you get ridiculously detailed and nitpicky when it's not called for"* - Your post is literally indistinguishable from that description.

Comment: How do I specify a name for that object?  cars[0] = Car("Camaro", "Yellow", 25000); ends up in an error C2512 (Visual Studio) "no appropriate default constructor available" in file "xmemory0" on line 588...

Comment: You should cut out all the irrelevant noise and post some code that actually illustrates and reproduces the problem.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to use the code provided to create an object in a vector of objects with the required data of name, color, price.

Comment: Don't use `cars[0] = Car("Camaro", "Yellow", 25000);`. Use the version with `push_back`.

Comment: Also it looks like your `cars` definition is wrong. Is it a vector at all? Show how you define `cars`.

Comment: #include <vector> . . . 
vector<Car> cars;

Comment: `cars` looks good. Show a short code which uses `push_back` to add a car to `cars` and causes error.

Comment: I got it working!  Not sure what I did differently, but all of a sudden it's letting me do the function calls and outputting the correct information.  the push_back(Car(name, color, price)) function works fine now and I can call each cell of the vector and output its information.  Thanks for all the help, everybody! especially @WojtekSurowka and Alan.

Comment: Tell your professor to pass his strings by const reference.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have so far?

With your original code:

```
std::vector<Car> cars;
cars.push_back(Car("Camaro", "Yellow", 25000.0d))
```

Should give you exactly what you're looking for.

To create a Car on the stack you would say:

`Car& myCar = Car("GTi", "Grey", 25000.0d);`

Comment: Why pointers? You should avoid using pointers in C++ unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Using pointers with the STL made copying, allocation more efficient. Is that no longer the case?

Comment: Isn't your "creating on the stack" making an unnecessary copy?

Comment: It wouldn't be very efficient to store pointers because you need to allocate for *each element*.

Comment: It's 400 lines of code. I'm not tremendously worried about processing/memory efficiency right now, just efficacy. Thanks.

Comment: @JordanRiley - this is good thinking. "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil", and using pointers by default for presumed efficiency is very wrong.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Do you have references to "avoid using pointers in C++?"

Comment: @svenoaks: Good point, though RVO should take care of the unnecessary copy.

Comment: @JordanRiley: Knowing when to use pointers vs objects, isn't about optimization, it's about knowing why one should be used over the other. It's like saying "It's okay to use an array, even though I need add and remove elements at random."

Comment: And in this case there is no apparent reason to use pointers. Or if there is, you could explain it in your answer.

Comment: @Alan - for instance "Never use owning raw pointers and delete, except in rare cases when implementing your own low-level data structure (and even then keep that well encapsulated inside a class boundary)." - http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/